# Share my current project using git

Tags: git

I have a project which is managed myself. And I want to use git to manage it.

And the project is located at: `/home/maven/workspace/tmkproject`(this is my current working directory). And I am using the Eclipse IDE.

I do not prefer to use the `git init` under my working directory to create the repository .

I want to create the repository at a certain location like `/home/maven/gitrepo`.

Then I pull the project to my directory.

So in my situation, how to make it?

Because the project may be worked with more people in my team.

Comment: they can just git clone from your `/home/maven/workspace/tmkproject` and work from there. git communication doesn't have to be over http. Is this wht you are asking?

Comment: If you don't want to use git, then use SVN, Mercurial, or any of the other version control systems out there.

Comment: @CppLearner: People in my team can use the `git clone` to get the codes. I want to know how about me? I do not think I can use the `/home/maven/workspace/tmkproject` as the working directory?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. In general you want to have a master-fork style, right? There is a master repo, and everyone forks from it. It would be easier if you could rephrase the question if that's not what you want. and you can git clone (which is fork) from it. Use Github or Bitbucket to manage your repository. Mercurial gives you free private repo so if you need privacy use it.

Comment: and git init takes a path. git init /home/maven/gitrepo will create a repo at that location. I don't use maven so I don't know if that's a special location...

Comment: @CppLearner: Excuse me, maybe I do not express myself clearly. :(.  This is the git diagram:http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0103-tn.png. As you can see, it shows the working manner. People `pull` project from the server and submit them. Now my computer is served as the git server. So I think there may should be two copies of the project. One to be forked by others(include me) as the repository, and the other is my working copy. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes that's what I am saying master-fork manner. Let me see if I could answer this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want multiple people to work on a project using git.  Your idea is to put the repository in `/home/maven/gitrepo` and have everyone use that repository directly.  You *can* do this using the `GIT_DIR` environment variable, this isn't a good way to use git.

Instead, `/home/maven/gitrepo` should contain a repository and each person should have a clone of this repository.  Then they can push and pull as normal.

First, begin by dumping everything into git.  Make sure any temp and build files are out of the way or write a .gitignore file to make git ignore them.

```
cd /home/maven/workspace/tmkproject
git init
git add .
git commit -a
```

Now that you have a git repository in `/home/maven/workspace/tmkproject/.git` you need to get a copy into `/home/maven/gitrepo`.

```
cd /home/maven/gitrepo
git clone --bare /home/maven/workspace/tmkproject
```

This will make `/home/maven/gitrepo/tmkproject.git` which contains the contents of your `.git` directory.

Next step is to set up `/home/maven/workspace/tmkproject` to use `/home/maven/gitrepo/tmkproject.git` as a remote repository for pushing and pulling.

```
cd /home/maven/workspace/tmkproject
git remote add origin /home/maven/gitrepo/tmkproject.git
git fetch origin
```

Now you can push and pull from that central repository.

```
git push -u origin master    # send changes and set up the branch default
git push                     # now it will use the default
git pull                     # get new changes
```

Others can clone their own copies for development and push and pull.

```
cd ~user/devel
git clone /home/maven/gitrepo/tmkproject.git
```

You'll notice this is a bit of work to get set up, and eventually you'll want remote access.  It's often easier to use one of the existing git services like Github, Bitbucket, Gitorious or Gitlab.

Comment: `Next step is to set up /home/maven/workspace/tmkproject to use /home/maven/gitrepo/tmkproject.git as a remote repository for pushing and pulling`. !!! Thanks, this is what I want ! In fact, I want to differentiate the remote repository and the local working repository.

Comment: @hguser - git is distributed, so there is no important, or central repository. Schwern's steps are exactly right, but just to clarify, he created a repo in your current working directory, then cloned it to where you wanted your "central" repo, and he used `--bare`. Repos must be bare if you want to push to them. Other than that, and a little bit of directory structure difference, they're the same as regular repos. So, instead of creating a master repo and cloning a working copy, he created a repo of the working one, then cloned out a bare one that everyone can clone/push/pull from.

Comment: @GaryFixler: Right. It seems that I though git as svn. It is wrong. Then does it mean that if someone in my team use the `git clone git://xxxxxx --bare` to clone a local repository. Then this repository can be pull/push also?

Comment: @hguser - users don't want to `clone --bare`. When you `git init` in a folder, it creates a .git folder in there. That's literally the entire repo. Your working tree is outside the .git folder, inside of the folder you ran the init inside of. Bare repos can't have a user, so when you clone bare, it doesn't make a .git folder in the new clone; it puts all the contents instead where the working folder contents would be, right in the main folder. This is the major difference - bare repos have no user, thus no working tree area, thus don't need/don't have a .git folder.

Comment: Git users never push to each other; they only pull from each other. This is because pushing into someone's repo is an unexpected event for them, which could mess up their work, but users will always know if they're okay to pull things into their own repo. A bare repo can't have a user, or a working tree, so no one can interfere with it, thus it's okay to push to it. If your non-bare repo is named 'project', `clone --bare` will clone it to a folder named 'project.git', which won't have a .git folder inside it (it's almost as though it was absorbed from 'project/.git' up into 'project.git').

Comment: Oh, and to actually answer your question, cloning any repo, bare or not, will create a non-bare clone. Cloning any repo, bare or not, using `--bare`, will create a bare clone.

Comment: Thanks for your detail replay. I got it. :). I am new in git, and it seems that there are hard work to do.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer:* if you are a beginner with Git and/or Linux command line tools **do use `git init` in your project root directory, it will make things much easier for you.**

Also, it will only create a `.git` directory at the root of your root-level working copy so it will not be too intrusive.

If you do want to separate your working copy from a backup of your repo on your local machine, create two repos and push from your working copy to your "backup repo".

---

Git supports the `GIT_DIR` environment variable which can be used to override the default location of the `.git` directory. You can set it to `/home/maven/workspace/tmkproject` and type `git init`. Make sure to keep this variable correctly set at all time and to change it if you switch between two Git working copies corresponding to different repositories.

See [man git(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, great picture. That's master-fork style.

You have your master (probably `/home/maven/workspace/tmkprojec`).

You and your members can `git clone /home/maven/workspace/tmkprojec /path/to/saved/repo` over the filesystem...

Now, I don't know how you setup your computer as a git server, and I recommend DON'T do that. 
If you are not on the same network or don't have NFS (network-file system) setup, either you need SSH or server exposes.

Github / Bitbucket should solve your problem.

The best practice is as follows, using Bitbucket:

1. You are called scrum master. You create a team account on Bitbucket, adds your members to the team account.
2. You push the existing master repo to Bitbucket
3. You and your members will fork from that repo on Bitbucket
4. You and your memebrs will clone down the repo from Bitbucket onto your local machines
5. You and your members will push changes to your own forked rpeo on Bitbucket
6. When you complete a feature/think it is time to exchange code, you can submit a Pull request to the master.
7. You and your team members will take turn to do code review and merge in the source code.

The only reason I say Bitbucket is because it has free private repository. Otherwise, you can use Github. Doesn't matter.

Comment: We can not use the online code hosting service by security reason. And our team are all inside a local network. And we want the teamer can use `pull` the project by the username and password, then is there a better idea? Since I read this post:http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#apachehttp It seems that I can only use the apache?